# Microsoft Power Automate - conditions, or values are always null

Tags: excel, outlook, power-automate

I hope you can help us, we already spent with a colleague some time with finding a solution, without success.

First a bit of theory:
We have a specific ticketing system in the company, with very limited functionality. However, when a ticket is closed, it will send an email out to the creator. We want to include a link for a satisfaction survey there. However, we dont want to be sent after every ticket, but after lets say every 10th ticket. As no advanced integration of the system is possible, I came with this workaround:

- Email is sent from ticketing system
- To a specific shared inbox, where it is routed (based on specific email subject)
- When this routed email arrives, it will trigger MS power automate (MSPA further on)
- on OneDrive there is prepared excel file, with a table in it
- MSPA will use "add a row into an excel table"
- in the excel there is couple of functions used for adding incrementing ID, creating company email address out of an ticket creator name (his name is in email subject), and modulus function, which evaluates if ID number is dividable by 10, which results in TRUE or FALSE
- in MSPA there is an condition, which should evaluate if there is in modulus column TRUE
- if there is TRUE, and condition is evaluated as a correct, it should send an email to the email address mentioned in that excel row

The result is, that flow is going without any error, but the condition is always evaluated as false. I have tried to modify this setup with multiple different approaches:
- using get a row function, 
- creating additional table where only filtered data would be inserted (and therefore used for sending emails), but the result was always only adding empty rows
- and any other modifications either of excel table, playing with delays (in case these couple of formulas in excel will be slower than MSPA flow on the server) or amending conditions, with static or dynamic fields

Above mention process seems as the most effective and simpler one, but almost every one of these setup works, at least theoretically (I mean no external problems, like permissions, etc), but they all seemed to have similar issue - null value. Either condition was always false, or in input-output pairs upon investigation of logs input had gathered data, following output part was null.

What can be wrong? Can it be a problem, that all fields used in this setup are made out of formulas?

Here are some pics for illustration and showing the errors:
current process setup
[image]

details of condition evaluation result
[image]

from previous approaches, get a row function, it has loaded the data (in first table the ID column is called "0", we can see the first record has value 1.

[image]

And here output part of updating a row, we can see ID, and Mail are both null, even though they were loaded in previous step.
[image]

Any idea what we do wrong? Apologies if we have overlooked something obvious, we are not so skillful with this and just started to play around :)

Many thanks for all advices!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and I resolved doing this.

```
Conditition = empty(actionBody('Filtra_ID'))
```

Look at the image:

[image: Solve condition]

Comment: Hello Davidson, many thanks for your reply. However, to be honest, I am not sure If I got your point from that picture. I have tried to replicate this somehow, but I am not sure about the theory behind it... what exactly have you filtered out? And you have used also array? In what way please? Sorry for maybe dumb question...but Im just starting with this MSPA :) Thanks